# WordPress message on top of all pages

Tags: wordpress

since a few days I have this following message on top of all my pages created by using Wordpress:

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; // Exit if accessed directly. }

Why this message appears and How can I remove it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually these lines protects the page from direct access, some how you put these lines out of the php module.
So now you have to access your theme templates and find the appropriate template and you need to these lines with this code

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) 
{ exit; // Exit if accessed directly. }
?>
```

If you still having some problem please contact me I will try to help you.
NOTE: IF YOU ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH WORKING ON CODE MODULES PLEASE DON'T TRY THIS. LET ME ALLOW TO FIX IT.

Comment: What is strange is that these lines of code appears on top of my pages and users can see it.

Comment: i can understand this. if you like then share me your credentials, i would close this message permanently.

Comment: one most important thing is that if the problem is exactly the same as i think, then any one can access your content directly. which is not good in practice.